# BottomNavigationView Click event fires on debug version but not in release version

Tags: android, release

`BottomNavigationView` works perfectly on both the simulator and my phone, but when I make a release version and install it on my phone (while clicking on them changes the active button and apparently it works), but the click listener is not fired.

This is the code:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    ConstraintLayout cs = findViewById(R.id.container);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(item.getItemId()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_fa:
            return true;
        case R.id.nav_pin:
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

To make sure, I put a `Toast` in the beginning, but it does not show up either.

Comment: add  `.show()` method at the end of your toast